# Problemas DLL MMMReaderDotNet40 y MMMReaderHighLevelAPI C#

Tags: c#

Uso C# y Visual Studio 2015, es un ejemplo que trae el SDK de un lector de documentos "Gemalto AT9000 MK2".
Al intentar inicializar la aplicacion no encuentra la dll "MMMReaderHighLevelAPI". Inicialmente solo estaba "MMMReaderDotNet40"dentro de la carpeta del bin, copie y pegue la dll solicitada pero el error persiste. No se si debo hacer un paso mas o darle alguna referencia dentro del IDE.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has seguido los pasos que indica el error?

Comment: Realizando una busqueda veo esto http://systemexplorer.net/es/file-database/file/mmmreaderhighlevelapi-dll/13481684  quizas deberias ver sino hace falta un SDK de terceros para tener esa dll. Segun veo es creada por 3M

Comment: Si segui los pasos pero sin exito.

Comment: Leandro, la que uso es creada por gemalto, tambien probe la del 3M pero me da el mismo inconveniente